# how to get the value of next node in xml using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="11928043053884448382" options="IgnoreChildOrder IgnoreNamespaces IgnoreWhitespace IgnoreXmlDecl " fragments="no" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
    <xd:node match="2">
        <xd:node match="2">
            <xd:node match="19">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:add>Y</xd:add>
                </xd:node>
            </xd:node>
            <xd:add match="/2/2/11" opid="2" />
            <xd:change match="18" name="OWNINGSITE">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:remove match="1" />
                </xd:node>
            </xd:change>
            <xd:add match="/2/2/2-9" opid="1" />
            <xd:change match="17" name="STATUS">
                <xd:node match="2">
                    <xd:remove match="1" />
                </xd:node>
            </xd:change>
            <xd:remove match="14-16" />
            <xd:remove match="13" subtree="no">
                <xd:remove match="1-2" />
            </xd:remove>
            <xd:remove match="11" opid="2" />
            <xd:remove match="10" />
            <xd:remove match="2-9" opid="1" />
            <xd:remove match="1" />
        </xd:node>
        <xd:node match="5">
            <xd:node match="3">
                <xd:node match="11">
                    <xd:change match="1">0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1</xd:change>
                </xd:node>
            </xd:node>
        </xd:node>
    </xd:node>
    <xd:descriptor opid="1" type="move" />
    <xd:descriptor opid="2" type="move" />
</xd:xmldiff>
```

I have written the c# code snippet to get the value of "match". I am able to get the value of first match i.e. "2" but am unable to go to the next node and get the value of its "match".
My output should be:

first match value 2

second match value 2

third match value 19

```
    namespace demo
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\\shreyas\\NX_Temp\\NX_Temp\\000048_A\\CompareReport3D.xml");
               // XmlNodeList nodeList1= xmlDoc.ReadNode();

                XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("*");
               string[] arr1 = new string[10];
                int i = 0;
               foreach (XmlNode node1 in nodeList)
               {
                   XmlNode personalNode = node1.SelectSingleNode("/node");
                   arr1[i] = node1.Attributes["match"].Value;
                   Console.WriteLine("first match value:" +arr1[i]);
                   i++;
//upto this point am getting the output and the exception after this
                   arr1[i] = personalNode.Attributes["match"].Value;
                   Console.WriteLine("second match value:" + arr1[i]);
                   i++;
                   arr1[i] = personalNode.Attributes["match"].Value;
                   Console.WriteLine("third match value:" + arr1[i]);

               }

            }
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using XDocument (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx). It makes the XML DOM traversal much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a *recursive call*.

Create a method:

```
 public static void TraverseXml(XmlNodeList nodeList)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node1 in nodeList)
        {
            if (node1.Attributes!=null && node1.Attributes["match"] != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("first match value:" + node1.Attributes["match"].Value);
            }
            TraverseXml(node1.ChildNodes);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

And from your main method call :

```
static void Main()
        {

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\\shreyas\\NX_Temp\\NX_Temp\\000048_A\\CompareReport3D.xml");
           // XmlNodeList nodeList1= xmlDoc.ReadNode();

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("*");
            TraverseXml(nodeList);
        }
```

Comment: Sure. No worries. Please mark it as answer, if it answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

little fix for correct output information :)

```
public static List<XmlNode> TraverseXml(XmlNodeList nodeList, int counter = 1)
    {
        List<XmlNode> matchNode = new List<XmlNode>();


        foreach (XmlNode node1 in nodeList)
        {
            if (node1.Attributes != null && node1.Attributes["match"] != null)
            {

                matchNode.Add(node1.Attributes["match"]);
                Console.WriteLine(counter + " match value:" + node1.Attributes["match"].Value);
                counter++;
            }
            TraverseXml(node1.ChildNodes, counter);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        return matchNode;
    }
```

Comment: How can i store the match values in an arraylist?

Comment: add this to function, (make return value for this function: List<XmlNode>, add return matchNode). List<XmlNode> matchNode = new List<XmlNode>();
            matchNode.Add(node1.Attributes["match"]);